# BindingResolutionException Target class [hash] does not exist after deploy

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-8

I wanted to deploy my laravel 8.0 project via ssh pull to production. I did composer update in ssh to my ubuntu server and after that my website is down and showing 500 error.

when I turn on debug mode in production it shows below error:

> Target class [hash] does not exist.

[image]

my website worked well before pull and composer update and after that this happened.

also there is no problem in local environment and it works properly.

my .env file in production also exists and the details are set.

I have tried lots of ways for resolving the error but none of these works:

1. changing permisions for bootstrap and also for the whole project :

   `sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache`

   `sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`
2. removing and reverting bootstrap folder
3. `composer dump-autoload`
4. `php artisan config:cache`
5. `composer update` and `sudo composer update`

I also tried these commands but none of them worked:

`php artisan route:clear`

`php artisan view:clear`

`php artisan config:cache`

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan config:clear`

I've searched alot and tried many ways but no result.
could any one say what is wrong please? thanks alot.

Comment: simply you are importing a class named `hash` in a file but the class does not exist. may be the class name is `Hash`??

Comment: I searched for the places hash has been used and no where I found it except in config.php file as "Hash". how should I solve it?  by the way the project used to work before composer update from ubuntu server.

Comment: is the class `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash`?? this class is used for hashing a string.

Comment: yes it is this 'Hash' => 'Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Hash' , but as I said I used it no where.